# How to store system("date +%s) output to variable?c++

Tags: command-line

Here's my problem, when I try to do

```c
long int second;
second=system("date +%s);
```

and then export the "second" to a text file i get `0` instead of `1403109...`

How can I export the output of this command to a text whenever the second changes?

Comment: Please see the documentation of `system()` function. It returns the exit code of the command (here `date`) and not the output of it. Also, it would be a bad practice to use a system call in order to take the current second since 1970, but you could use something from `time.h` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242963/get-the-current-time-in-seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The output of `system("date +%s")` can not be stored in a variable as you tried.**

From `man system`

```c
int system(const char *command);
```

> `system` executes  a  command  specified  in  command  by calling `/bin/sh -c command`, and returns after the command has been completed.

`system` does not return the output of the command executed. It returns `0` if command is successfully executed and shell is not available. Otherwise returns some integer exit status.

> **How can I export the output of this command to a text file**

**Method-1:** Redirection (already mentioned by @Jobin): call system as,

```c
system("date +\%s >> text.txt");
```

**Method-2:** Use `popen`, It will return a `FILE*` which you can use to read the output of the command.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp,*outputfile;
  char var[40];

  fp = popen("date +%s", "r");
  while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL) 
    {
      printf("%s", var);
    }
  pclose(fp);

  outputfile = fopen("text.txt", "a");
  fprintf(outputfile,"%s\n",var);
  fclose(outputfile);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get time you could use functions in time.h
System function returns only return code, instead of output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* outputfile = popen(REPLACE_WITH_COMMAND, "r");
    // Now, in the variable outputfile, is output as pointer
    //   to FILE object. Operate with this as file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can i export this to cout or text.txt?
Iam interested in finding when the output changes value and save the new value in a text..thx

Answer (score 0):

You could directly redirect the output to a file using the redirection operator `>` as follows:

```
system("date +\%s > filename");
```

Remember you need to escape the `%` and replace `filename` by the file you want the output to redirect to.

The `>` operator redirects the output of the command to the left hand side to the file on the right hand side by overwriting the contents of `filename` (if any) with the output, instead of printing it to standard output. If you want to append the output instead of overwriting the previous contents, you could use `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: THANK YOU MY FRIEND:) now can you lead me how to get the content of the file and make condition like "if(filename1!=filename2){filename1=filename2)}

Comment: @user1: That would form a new, separate question.